# Emulating angular fancy inputs

Tags: angular, angular-forms

The powers-that-be have decided, weeks before launch, that they like the modern look of input controls that are underlines rather than boxes, with the labels that slide out of the way when the input has focus.

This page demonstrates the effect:
https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/input
Click on *First name* to see the label move.

My reusable component looks like this:

```
<span 
    [ngClass]="styleClass" 
    class="wrapper">

    <label 
        [ngClass]="{'text-center': largeLabel, 'm-h-0': largeLabel}" 
        [attr.aria-labelledby]="id + '-label'">

        <span 
            [ngClass]="{'large-label': largeLabel}">
            {{ label }}
        </span>
    </label>

    <input 
        #element [value]="(isUppercase)?(textValue |uppercase): textValue" 
        (keyup)="onChange($event)" 
        (focusout)="executeAllTouchedFunctions(); 
        onChange($event)"
        [ngClass]="{'ng-invalid': !control?.valid && (control?.touched || control?.dirty) && !control.disabled, 'ng-dirty': control?.dirty, 'ng-touched': control?.touched}"
        [type]="type" 
        class="form-control" 
        [placeholder]="placeholder || ''" 
        [attr.aria-describedby]="(describedById) ? describedById : controlName?.name + '-described-by-id'"
        [name]="name" 
        [attr.aria-labelledby]="id + '-textField'" 
        [required]="isRequired" 
        [attr.maxlength]="maxlength" 
        [attr.aria-required]="isRequired"
        [disabled]="disabled" 
        (focus)="onFocus(e)" 
        [attr.aria-invalid]="!control?.valid && (control?.touched || control?.dirty)" />
</span>
```

So, as far as I can tell, to affect the label, when the input has focus, I'll need to use JavaScript (with some sort of $(input).parent().find(label)) thing.

I've added the onFocus() event, and am capturing the event, but not sure what to do with it.

```
onFocus(event:FocusEvent) {
    console.log(FocusEvent);
}
```

this simply returns

"FocusEvent() { [native code] }"

I was expecting some objects I could work with. Can I get hold of the input object in the DOM, so I can find its associated label?

Or am I overthinking this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> input controls that are underlines rather than boxes, with the labels that slide out of the way when the input has focus.

This style of input field comes from Google's [Material Design](https://material.io/design/) system.

The Angular team created the Angular Material library so you don't have to implement these components yourself. [Here's the documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview) for `<mat-form-field>`.

> this simply returns
>
> "FocusEvent() { [native code] }"

You are logging the constructor `FocusEvent` instead of logging your `event` object. If you change your code to `console.log(event)`, you should get an object that looks like this:

```
bubbles: false
cancelBubble: false
cancelable: false
composed: true
currentTarget: null
defaultPrevented: false
detail: 0
eventPhase: 0
isTrusted: true
path: (9) [input.s-input.js-search-field., div.ps-relative, form#search.searchbar.js-searchbar, div.-container, header.top-bar.js-top-bar.top-bar__network._fixed, body.question-page.unified-theme, html.html__responsive, document, Window]
relatedTarget: null
returnValue: true
sourceCapabilities: InputDeviceCapabilities {firesTouchEvents: false}
srcElement: input.s-input.js-search-field.
target: input.s-input.js-search-field.
timeStamp: 100675.87499995716
type: "focus"
view: Window {postMessage: ƒ, blur: ƒ, focus: ƒ, close: ƒ, parent: Window, …}
which: 0
```

And you can access the input field as `event.target`.

Comment: I know i'm supposed to wait a day or two to assign as an answer, but <mat-form-field> is the best solution to my problem.